# Getting error when build a webpack5 bundled vue3 app with electron builder?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, desktop, electron-builder

I was trying to use the electron builder for convert my vue3 app to an exe file. My app is a vue3 project and it is bundled with webpack5. I added electron builder for my project using **vue add electron-builder** command and then I run the **npm install** command. Both commands was executed without any issue. Then I tried to run the **npm run electron:serve** and **npm run electron:build** commands. Then I got the following error message as the command not found.

**macdeMacBook-Pro-3:ican-property-web mac$ npm run electron:serve

> client@0.0.0 electron:serve
> vue-cli-service electron:serve
> sh: vue-cli-service: command not found

macdeMacBook-Pro-3:ican-property-web mac$ npm run electron:build

> client@0.0.0 electron:build
> vue-cli-service electron:build**

Please see the scripts section in package.json file.

"scripts": {
"serve": "vite preview",
"build": "webpack --mode production",
"lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
"dev": "webpack serve --open --config webpack.config.js",
"electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
"electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
"i18n:report": "vue-cli-service i18n:report --src "./src/**/*.?(js|vue)" --locales "./src/undefined/**/*.json"",
"postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
"postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
"preview": "vite preview",
"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"
}

"npm": "^9.6.1",
"vue": "^3.2.47",
"webpack": "^5.80.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.3",
"webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
"webpack-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.1"

Node Version : v18.18.0

Kindly support me to fix this issue. Thanks.